# How old is Purim Torah?

Tags: history, torah-study, purim, humor

How old is the tradition of Purim Torah?  The [Wikipedia article linked from our PT policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) notes a disputed claim of Purim Torah in the talmud (Hulin 139b), with some saying that while the talmud contains *humor* it doesn't contain the kind of *satire* that characterizes modern Purim Torah.

I am not asking about *Purimspiels* (dramatic presentations), though that might be related.  What is the oldest case we know of Purim Torah that mimics teaching (written or oral)?

Comment: Very interesting question. I am thinking that it might be related to when the first Purim parade occurred. Costumes and a party atmosphere leads to humor.

Comment: A great question i think that is connected to your question is: how does the prohibition of Gilui Panim BaTorah factor into Purim Torah

Comment: Feels like we need a Purim Torah NOT In Jest tag for questions like this ;)

Answer (score 4):

The printed editions of [Machzor Vitry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simhah_ben_Samuel_of_Vitry) contain a lengthy *piyyut* for *ma'ariv* of Purim, which starts with the words [*Leil shikurim hu zeh halailah*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=10172&st=&pgnum=187&hilite=) ("Tonight is a night of drunkenness").

While some seem to have taken this *piyyut* at face value, it certainly appears to be a parody (or "Purim Torah") of the *piyyut* recited on the night of Pesach (*leil shimurim*).

In terms of provenance and dating, it is attributed to a R. Menachem b. Aharon. While it is not clear exactly when he lived, [this article](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/14512027.pdf) by Eliezer Brodt quotes [Israel Davidson](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=YbnZlHrsA-wC&dq=davidson%20parody%20jewish%20literature&pg=PP1&ots=R9BkKVMsWb&sig=qRv-H7AnMhjCD-60zkAJ3G42SUg&hl=en&prev=http://www.google.com/search%3Fhl%3Den&q=davidson%20parody%20jewish%20literature&sa=X&oi=print&ct=title&redir_esc=y) as dating him to between 1140 and 1244.

Answer (score 3):

[Kalonymus ben Kalonymus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalonymus_ben_Kalonymus) (13th-14th century) authored such a work entitled Masseket Purim, a parody for the Feast of Purim. (I think; see [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1450670?Search=yes&resultItemClick=true&searchText=Book&searchText=art&searchText=jew&searchUri=%2Faction%2FdoBasicResults%3Fpagemark%3DcGFnZU1hcms9NA%253D%253D%26amp%3Bed%3D%26amp%3Bsi%3D1%26amp%3Bso%3Dold%26amp%3BQuery%3DBook%2Bart%2Bjew%26amp%3Brefreqid%3Dsearch%253Ae0b14bbe3beab11879abe128ca27720b%26amp%3BsearchType%3DfacetSearch%26amp%3Bsd%3D%26amp%3Bfilter%3Djid%253A10.2307%252Fj100195&ab_segments=0%2Ftbsub-1%2Frelevance_config_with_tbsub&seq=12#metadata_info_tab_contents), 137ff., for a brief description of the work)

I believe [Immanuel the Roman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanuel_the_Roman) (13th-14th century) authored a work of this genre as well entitled [Makhberet Imanuel](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C)

Comment: I write hesitatingly because I havent examined these texts myself so I cannot attest to the exact style. All I know about them is from references to these works as rabbinic purim related parodies.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21108&st=&pgnum=178

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't have a chance to look through it yet. Is that the medieval rationalist tract _Alilot Devarim_?

Comment: That is the title and time period. I can't confirm the philosophy.

Comment: @DoubleAA If it is what I suspect it is, then it is a powerful anti-superstitious tract that lambasts the anti-Maimonideans. It is satire in the same sense that A Modest Proposal is; it is perhaps written in a particular less than serious literary mode, but is nevertheless a serious work. Not sure it qualifies as Purim Torah. Thanks again for the link.

Comment: I was more addressing the style. It's 90% pesukim interwoven much like you'd expect in a purim kiddush.