# What is the difference between simcha and oneg?

Tags: shabbat, words, translation, yom-tov

The [Mishna Berura (529:16)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.529.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) notes there is a difference between "simcha" and "oneg" regarding Chol HaMoed and Yom Tov, but doesn't seem to elaborate. I always assumed they were relatively interchangeable, but clearly there is a clear delineation - what is the difference between "simcha" and "oneg"?

Comment: are pleasure and joy the same thing?

Comment: @wfb sure, they're synonyms which have some contrast. Those  differences in definition are what I'm asking (perhaps similar to the question about the difference between simcha and gilah)

Comment: He is *mechalek* between *simchah* and *kavod ve'oneg*. So for example there is no obligation to wear honourable clothes for *chol ha'moed*.

Comment: You could also add in, 'sasson', 'gila', 'rina', 'ditza' and 'chedva' as well....

Comment: @Dov Feel free to ask a new question - I'm definitely curious about those as well! Some of those have been addressed previously https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75493/sasson-and-simcha-what-in-the-world-is-going-on

Comment: While having no basis for saying so, I would assume the difference is that simchah is has an internal locus, meaning that it is borne out of internal stimuli (IOW you make your own simcha) while oneg has an external locus (IOW the oneg is provided by the yom tov - that is to say, you get oneg because of the Yom Tov, as opposed to giving yourself simcha because of the Yom Tov).

Comment: I think in this case we are looking for  a halachic difference between simcha and oneg yom tov

Comment: @Yehuda oneg would be internal and simchas external as oneg is something that doesn't need any external demonstration whereas simcha is always expressed in some external way such as smiling, laughing, dancing, etc

Comment: I think simcha is a bit stronger. Oneg Shabbat can probably be fulfilled with any psychological pleasure, but I don't know about Simchat Yom Tov.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Some](http://etzion.gush.net/vbm/archive/yomyom/dafyomyomi/2012-12-04.php) suggest based on the [Zohar (2:88b)](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.2.88b.7?vhe=New_Torat_Emet_Zohar&lang=bi) that the difference between Simcha on Yom Tov and Oneg on Shabbos is:

> הזוהר מחלק בין שמחת יום טוב שהיא שמחה שאמורה לצאת החוצה ולכלול בתורה
> את העני והגר, היתום והאלמנה, לבין שמחת השבת שהיא שמחה פנימית שמתקיימת
> אצל האדם הפרטי גם בלי לשתף אחרים בשמחתו - Happiness on Yom Tov is a happiness which must externally incorporate other individuals, i.e. the poor, converts, orphans, and widows, while the happiness on Shabbos is more of an internal focus.

2. Rav Chaim Kanievsky in Derech Sicha writes the difference between between Oneg Shabbos and Simchas Yom Tov is that Oneg Shabbos can be accomplished many times throughout Shabbos while Simchas Yom Tov can be achieved by eating/drinking once.

The [Teshuvos Chasam Sofer OC (168)](https://www.sefaria.org/Responsa_Chatam_Sofer%2C_Orach_Chayim.168.4-5?lang=en) offers a halachic difference between Oneg Shabbos and Simchas Yom Tov:

> ודע דיש חילוק בין שבת לי"ט דבשבת עונג מפורש ולא אכילה ע"כ המתענג
> בתענית יי"ח עונג שבת ואמנם מי שאינו מתענה אינו יי"ח אכילה אא"כ מתענג
> באותה אכילה וע"כ אסור לאכול מן המנחה ולמעלה בעש"ק כדי שיאכל לתיאבון
> בלילה. ואמנם בי"ט שמחה כתיב בי' ואין שמחה בלא אכילה כדאמרי' במ"ק ט'
> ע"א ואפילו ליכא בשר שלמים ויין מ"מ אכילה ושתיי' בעי ואפי' התענית עונג
> אסור (אם לא תענית חלום משום סכנות נפשות) אך אינו מפורש שתהי' אכילה
> מעונגת דוקא ואם אוכל אפי' אינו מתענג יי"ח אכילה וע"כ לא פשיט כ"כ איסור
> אכיל' בעי"ט ממנחה ולמעלה כמו בע"ש - One who enjoys fasting on Shabbos
> and does so fulfills Oneg Shabbos, while if he were to eat that
> Shabbos without pleasure then he would not fulfill Oneg Shabbos. On
> the other hand, on Yom Tov one must eat and drink even if it is not an
> Oneg for him (unless fasting for a nightmare due to sakanas nefashos).